# VS2010 proj compiles but proj references are shown as broken and R# not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, projects-and-solutions

In Visual Studio 2010 SP1, there is a large number of C# projects in one Global solution.
Both Debug & Release output of all lib projects is set to a common `Assemblies` dir.
**All references are to the projects**, not to the resulting DLLs in the `Assemblies` dir.
Some libraries have their own solution files with a small subset of projects.
Everything compiles and works fine when using the global.sln

**Problem:** When opening just LibC.sln, it **compiles fine**, but the References\ folder shows errors with all project references, and Resharper 6.1.1 cannot locate them. Deleting all `*.suo`, `bin\`, and `obj\` dirs, clearing R# cache and restarting visual studio does not help. Sometimes the problem goes away on its own.

```
- SVN\
  - global.sln
  - LibA\
    - LibA.csproj
  - LibB\
    - LibB.csproj
  - LibC\
    - LibC.csproj
    - LibC.sln
- Assemblies\
  - LibA.dll
  - LibB.dll
  - LibC.dll
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net for us to take a look at?

Comment: Dmitri, I already cross-posted this issue to R# @ http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-289611 and will try to come up with some simple solution demonstrating it. The problem is that this is not consistent, and at some point the problem simply goes away, yet could resurface at any moment. Based on another post, it might be related to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643835/msbuild-uses-wrong-config-when-building-non-default-config-projects-referenced-but-not-included-in-solution